# How to decode the string encoded by document.write in BeautifulSoup, Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As title says, I'm stuck here for hours with no documentation or any solution.
This is the website where I started: https://idhsaa.org/directory. I cannot access the Email IDs not only over here, but also inside the individual websites that opens up upon clicking on the school names.

The format that I found is something like this:

```
<p>
    <script>
        document.write(window.atob('PGEgaHJlZj0nbWFpbHRvOnNwZWNrZXI3M0B5YWhvby5jb20nPkVtYWlsPC9hPg=='));
    </script>
    <a href="mailto:pincockt@aberdeen58.org">Email</a>
    </br>
</p>
```

I managed to get the encoded code that looks something like this:

```
mailto:<script>document.write(window.atob('PGEgaHJlZj0nbWFpbHRvOmFkbWluQGlkaHNhYS5vcmcnPmFkbWluQGlkaHNhYS5vcmc8L2E+'));</script>
```

The question is, how do I decode this to get the Email IDs?
Depending on what I saw in the above output that I got, I assume, I need to decode that to get the actual email.

Here's the code that I'd been working on:

```
def url_parser(url):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246',
    }
    html_doc = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def data_fetch(url):
    soup = url_parser(url)
    table = soup.find('table').find('tbody')
    rows = table.find_all('tr')

    data = []
    for row in rows:
        school_name = row.find_all('a')

        for school in school_name:
            if 'school?' in school.get('href'):
                school_website = url.replace('/directory', f'/{school_web_id}')

                school_site = url_parser(school_website)
                principal_email_encoded = school_site.find_all('a')
                for principal_email in principal_email_encoded:
                    email = principal_email.get('href')
                    if 'maito:<script>' in email:
                        print(email.replace('maito:<script>', '').replace(';</script>', ''))



def main():
    url = "https://idhsaa.org/directory"
    data_fetch(url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are base64 encoded strings, you can decode the value by using the [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) module included in the Python Standard library.

For example, after extracting the encoded string you can do the following:

```py
import base64
encoded_str = "PGEgaHJlZj0nbWFpbHRvOmFkbWluQGlkaHNhYS5vcmcnPmFkbWluQGlkaHNhYS5vcmc8L2E+"
decoded_html = base64.b64decode(encoded_str).decode("utf-8")
print(decoded_html)
```

Output:

```html
"<a href='mailto:admin@idhsaa.org'>admin@idhsaa.org</a>"
```

Comment: I was near to the answer and you solved it. Many thanks! I had opened [this](https://www.knowledgewalls.com/johnpeter/books/good-javascript-examples/base64-encode-and-decode-using-btoa-and-atob-methods-in-javascript-with-example) website and I saw your answer!

Answer (score 1):

window.atob decodes a base64 encoded string.

You can use base64 to decode it like that:

```
import base64
encoded = "PGEgaHJlZj0nbWFpbHRvOmFkbWluQGlkaHNhYS5vcmcnPmFkbWluQGlkaHNhYS5vcmc8L2E+"
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
```

You can then use bs4 to extract the email like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded, features="html.parser")
soup.find("a")["href"]  # mailto:admin@idhsaa.org
```